# MySQL select last six moths, then the last years

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I  have an MySQL database for a blogpage I am working on. I would need a bit of help to realize the archive Menu I have in mind.

the DB has a column titled "Date" as a timestamp format. I want to select the last six months in which an article was published. My question is, how i could select the last six entries from the "Date" column, that have a different month value. The query should ignore the date and the time, only the month matters.

One idea I had, was to add another column to the DB that only stores the year and the month values. Of these I could do "Select Distinct from "MonthYear" limit 6; Would you agree that that works?

After I selected those months, for all the older articles I want to do the same for years. How could I select all years in which articles were posted, except the years that are allready covered by the previous monthwise selection?

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing, I hope you understand it and can help me.

Comment: The question IS a bit confusing. I'm SURE that you're capable of asking a less confusing question, maybe by reference to the SO guidelines and/or previous questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Month(Date) ORDER BY Month(Date) DESC) AS ArticleOrder
,ArticleID
, etc
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score -1):

Query for months. Returns in "year-month" format.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%Y-%m') m FROM `table` GROUP BY m ORDER BY m DESC LIMIT 6
```